# TinyMapper mapping with list of entity object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, tinymapper

I have started using tinymapper in my project for object-to-object mapping and succeeded for single object to single object mapping, but I am stuck when I want to map the whole list of entity object to list of DTO class. Can you please help me out. I googled but didn't find any solution. Can anyone please help me out?

I am able to map single object to object by using the below code:

```
var sq = new SurveyQuestion
            {
                SurveyId = 61,
                Question = "John",
                QuestionDescription = "Doe",
                Type = "DB",
                Selector = "TB",
                QuestionId = "QID1",
                SubSelector = "TX"
             }
TinyMapper.Bind<Survey, surveyDto>();
var result = TinyMapper.Map<surveyDto>(sq);
```

But I am stuck when I want to map the whole list of survey entity to surveyDto entity:

```
List<Survey> survey = _surveyRepository.All().ToList();
TinyMapper.Bind<List<Survey>, List<SurveyDto>>();
List<SurveyDto> surveyDto = TinyMapper.Map<List<SurveyDto>>(survey);
```

I am getting the this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<SurveyDto>' to
>   'SurveyDto'"

Answer (score 2):

You should create the same mapping, but instead describe it as for object-to-object you should describe it as list-to-list. So both your destination and source objects will be a lists and you describe you mapping configuration how to map each element of source list to each element of destination list. Its pretty simple

**UPDATE**

SO, it should be smth like that:

```
TinyMapper.Bind<List<Survey>, List<SurveyDto>>(config => 
{
    // Configure you config
});
```

Another thing is that maybe you should write your custom mapping class.

And also there is a good question: does TinyMapper support collection binding? If not than you can not do it

Comment: can you please provide me the code to bind and Map list-to-list? I am new to tinymapper so i dont know?

Comment: @Ronak just change types and write correc configuration

Comment: `List<Survey> survey = _surveyRepository.All().ToList(); //getting all records from table
TinyMapper.Bind<List<Survey>, List<SurveyDto>>(); //Binding mapper
List<SurveyDto> surveyDto = TinyMapper.Map<List<SurveyDto>>(survey); //gives error`

Comment: Many thanks for the code!! @andrew  you have provided code for Binding List<T> to List<V> . But not provided code for mapping? Can you please update code?? It will be too much helpful for me.

Comment: Have you read my full update? Are you sure that TinyMapper supports binding of collection? About configuration I think you know what write there

Answer (score 2):

Try this [one](https://github.com/TinyMapper/TinyMapper/issues/32)

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var fromDatabase = new List<Survey>
        {
            new Survey { Id = 1, Data = "Data1" },
            new Survey { Id = 2, Data = "Data2" }
        };

        TinyMapper.Bind<List<Survey>, List<SurveyDto>>();

        var dto = TinyMapper.Map<List<SurveyDto>>(fromDatabase);
    }


    public sealed class Survey
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }


    public sealed class SurveyDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```